# Remove URL encoding from parameter

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url

When I am giving input to get method..

> example: http://google.com/

it returns out into

> /?domain=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F in the URL.

I want to make it

> /?domain=http://google.com/ so that it looks nice.

how can I make that change?

is it possible from php or have to use javascript or .htaccess or any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode a URI via javascript:

```
decodeURIComponent("/?domain=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F")
```

returns `"/?domain=http://google.com/"`

Comment: that decodes well but how can I make it display in url replacing older one?